# Depletion layer of solar cell?

Tags: light-emitting-diodes, solar-cells

What happens to depletion layer of solar cells when light is falling on it?
Please reply as soon as possible.

Thank you

Comment: What, you are taking a test and need the answer?

Answer (score 1):

It's called depletion region since the region is depleted of charge carries. But practically we can have generation of charge carries when light is on. They get drifted to the p or n side depending on their charge due to the electric field present in the depletion region